# Gulpfile JS Less

Tags: gulp, less

При запуске gulp в папке src/css почему появляются 2 файла

[image: css]

второй файл я подключил через import

[image: smartgrid]

Где ошибка в в файле не могу догнать подскажите

```js
var gulp           = require('gulp'),
    smartgrid      = require('smart-grid');
  gutil          = require('gulp-util' ),
  less           = require('gulp-less'),
  gcmq = require('gulp-group-css-media-queries');
  browserSync    = require('browser-sync'),
  concat         = require('gulp-concat'),
  uglify         = require('gulp-uglify'),
  cleanCSS       = require('gulp-clean-css'),
  rename         = require('gulp-rename'),
  del            = require('del'),
  imagemin       = require('gulp-imagemin'),
  cache          = require('gulp-cache'),
  autoprefixer   = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  //ftp            = require('vinyl-ftp'),
  notify         = require("gulp-notify"),
  rsync          = require('gulp-rsync');
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');


gulp.task('grid', function() {
    smartgrid('src/less', {
    outputStyle: 'less', /* less || scss || sass || styl */
    columns: 12, /* number of grid columns */
    offset: '30px', /* gutter width px || % */
    mobileFirst: false, /* mobileFirst ? 'min-width' : 'max-width' */
    container: {
        maxWidth: '1200px', /* max-width оn very large screen */
        fields: '30px' /* side fields */
    },
    breakPoints: {
        lg: {
            width: '1200px', /* -> @media (max-width: 1100px) */
        },
        md: {
            width: '992px'
        },
        sm: {
            width: '768px',
            fields: '15px' /* set fields only if you want to change container.fields */
        },
        xs: {
            width: '560px'
        }
        /* 
        We can create any quantity of break points.

        some_name: {
            width: 'Npx',
            fields: 'N(px|%|rem)',
            offset: 'N(px|%|rem)'
        }
        */
    }
  });
});



gulp.task('common-js', function() {
 return gulp.src([
  'src/js/common.js',
  ])
 .pipe(concat('common.min.js'))
 .pipe(uglify())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('src/js'));
});

gulp.task('js', ['common-js'], function() {
 return gulp.src([
  //'src/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  'src/js/common.min.js',
  ])
 .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('src/js'))
 .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
 browserSync({
  server: {
   baseDir: 'src'
  },
  notify: false,
  
 });
});

gulp.task('less', function() {
 return gulp.src('src/less/**/*.less')
 .pipe(less({outputStyle: 'expand'}).on("error", notify.onError()))
 .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', prefix : ''}))
 .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
 .pipe(gcmq())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 .pipe(cleanCSS()) 
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'))
 .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['less', 'js', 'browser-sync'], function() {
 gulp.watch('src/less/**/*.less', ['less']);
 gulp.watch(['libs/**/*.js', 'src/js/common.js'], ['js']);
 gulp.watch('src/*.html', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
 return gulp.src('src/img/**/*')
 .pipe(cache(imagemin())) // Cache Images
 .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img')); 
});

gulp.task('build', ['removedist', 'imagemin', 'less', 'js'], function() {

 var buildFiles = gulp.src([
  'src/*.html',
  'src/.htaccess',
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

 var buildCss = gulp.src([
  'src/css/main.min.css',
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));

 var buildJs = gulp.src([
  'src/js/scripts.min.js',
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));

 var buildFonts = gulp.src([
  'src/fonts/**/*',
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));

});


gulp.task('removedist', function() { return del.sync('dist'); });
gulp.task('clearcache', function () { return cache.clearAll(); });

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Comment: "второй файл я подключил через import" - import где прописан?

Answer (score 0):

разобрался, в таске less добавил

```
.pipe(concat('main.css'))
```

и при выходе уже один файл